# How to make use of scan() more clear

Tags: javascript, reactive-programming, frp, bacon.js

I want to make a simple web page using bacon.js. It should have a button which toggles a boolean state by mouse click.
After setting up the streams, the app should be initialized by sending an object to an init stream. Here i just send the desired initial boolean state of the toggle (`false`).
The code looks like this (i faked the button clicks and initialization):

```
// Helper function
var neg = function (a) { return !a; }; 

// Fake of initialization stream. End after one element
var init = Bacon.sequentially(500, [false]);  
// Fake of button click event stream.
var click = Bacon.repeatedly(1000, [{}]); 

var toggle = init.concat(click).scan(null, 
    function(a, b) { return a === null ? b : neg(a); }).skip(1).toEventStream();

toggle.log();
// Output: false, true, false, true, ....
```

The above code ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hhelwich/hrt2rtxu/)) works as expected, but i do not like that the `toggle` stream creation line is so complex.

If it would be possible to omit the seed value (take it from the stream) and if `scan` returns an `EventStream` instead of a `Property`, i could write:

```
var toggle = init.concat(click).scan(neg);
```

This could be read much nicer. Or if it would be possible to give the seed as stream i could just write:

```
var toggle = click.scan(init, neg);
```

Do you have any suggestions to make the code more clear?
Is there an alternative solution to using `scan`?
Should i make me an own `scan` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read what I wrote previously, ignore. it. :) This situation is exactly what flatMap is for: streams that create streams. Use flatMap.

```
// Helper function
var neg = function (a) { return !a; };

// Fake of initialization stream. End after one element
// Note the use of `later` instead of `sequentially`, by the way
var init = Bacon.later(500, false);

// Fake of button click event stream.
var click = Bacon.repeatedly(1000, [null]);

var toggle = init
    .flatMap(function(initVal) { return click.scan(initVal, neg) });

toggle.log();
```

Comment: I think you want to use `flatMap`

Comment: You're right Bergi. I realized this as I lay in bed last night. :)